# Automatically add repositories from dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a library with a dependency that requires a custom repo

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.chartboost:chartboost-sdk:8.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://chartboostmobile.bintray.com/Chartboost" }
}
```

This works fine, but it forces me to add  `maven { url "https://chartboostmobile.bintray.com/Chartboost" }` to every project that uses that library. I would like to know, is there a way to modify my own library so I wouldn't need to add the custom maven repo for that dependency? Something that would add all the repos in the library to the project. I tried switching `implementation` with `api` to no avail

Answer (score 0):

You can put your repository into `[USER_HOME]/gradle/init.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://chartboostmobile.bintray.com/Chartboost" }     
  }
}
```

then they are will be applied to all projects

Comment: Thanks, but that will require everyone to do the same as me. I want anyone to be able to do add my library to their project without configuration

Comment: Everyone else will have to do something and you can not avoid it. It's rather about how many lines everybody has to change. For common changes in all files, the gradle home is the appropriate place. I don't think you have other options